# Displaying new screen takes too much time! (threads maybe...?)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, android-intent

### TL;DR: My  intent takes too much time to start from a different thread, whereas starting from the main thread is very fast. I dont actually know if this is a problem with threads or with the `onFinish` method

So, I have a countdown timer. It counts down from twenty seconds, and `onFinish()` I have an intent. I am also periodically setting the text of my textView based on `millisUntilFinished`. **I noticed, that after the textView says `1 second left`, the intent starts after 3 seconds.**

But, if I am switching activities by using an intent from **OUTSIDE of the `onFinish` method** the next activity starts quickly. So,

## Why does starting an intent from a the `onFinish` method take longer than usual?

According to my little test with my timer, I decided that I need a better and faster way to start my intent, since clearly, the onFinish method launches after more time then the timer actually starts. So, what should I do to start my intent faster? I need it to be immediate...

```
 public void startTimer() {

        timer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                int seconds = (int) millisUntilFinished/1000;

                timetext.setText(seconds + ":00");

            }

            public void onFinish() {



                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameOver.class);
                intent.putExtra("score", score);  // pass your values and retrieve them in the other Activity using keyName
                intent.putExtra("classname", "com.example.ruchir.swapproperties.MainActivity");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }.start();

    }
```

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: try using MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent); or try using  runOnUiThread

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the `startActivity(intent)` outside of the timer as such:

```
    public void startTimer() {

    timer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            int seconds = (int) millisUntilFinished/1000;

            timetext.setText(seconds + ":00");

        }

        public void onFinish() {



            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameOver.class);
            intent.putExtra("score", score);  // pass your values and retrieve them in the other Activity using keyName
            intent.putExtra("classname", "com.example.ruchir.swapproperties.MainActivity");


        }
    }.start();

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Then, the `onFinish` method would be for the class. We would be overriding the wrong thing, right?

Comment: `onFinish` method is used inside `CountDownTimer`, and gets called when timer is finished with all ticks.

Comment: I'm sorry I was mistaken with my answer, your `onFinish` method is in the correct place, but try placing the `startActivity(intent)` outside of the counter.

Comment: You need to declare the `Intent` and everything outside of the timer. Sorry, but I'm looking around as much as I can to get a proper answer for you! Let me know what happens

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try :

```
public void onFinish() {
        cancel(); //Cancel the countdown

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameOver.class);
        intent.putExtra("score", score);  // pass your values and retrieve them in the other Activity using keyName
        intent.putExtra("classname", "com.example.ruchir.swapproperties.MainActivity");
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

`